# Character encoding issue when posting on Facebook wall

Tags: wordpress, encoding, facebook-wall

I'm running a WordPress site http://egeszsegakademia.org (Hungarian)

When I click the "Like" button embedded into my posts, it seems very strange on my Facebook wall (with full of special characters like '?' or '©' and so on). The same thing happens when I directly share the link of my post on my FB wall.

I'd looked for the solution through the web and I did everything suggested e.a. converting my theme's php files to UTF8 (- without BOM) with Notepad++, used "Convert WP Database to UTF-8" plugin to convert the entire content of my DB tables without any success.

Facebook debug shows some errors but I don't know how to fix them:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fegeszsegakademia.org%2F2011%2F12%2F29%2Fmire-jok-az-aminosavak%2F

Are these errors able to cause my character encoding problem while posting on FB wall?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hmm, strange. The characters seem to be UTF-8 encoded, and your content-type info matches that both in the response header, and the HTML document's head. Still, it seems like your data is being served as ISO-8859-1 to Facebook for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

when viewing source of your url, it seems there's a special character in the og:description that not even Firefox browser can figure out and displays as a back diamond with a white question mark inside of it.  It's just after the `&Aring;` part.